# SQL Error: 1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mybb

I'm trying to solve this error :

> 1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Query:

```
SELECT t.*, t.username AS threadusername, u.username, 
MATCH (t.subject) AGAINST ('test123 test') AS relevance 
FROM 123test_threads t
LEFT JOIN 123test_users u ON (u.uid = t.uid) 
WHERE t.fid='2' AND t.tid!='4' AND t.visible='1' AND t.closed NOT LIKE 'moved|%' 
AND MATCH (t.subject) AGAINST ('test123 test') >= '2' 
ORDER BY t.lastpost DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

whene i try to create a new thread in my multiforums website.

Comment: Don't post logins in public spaces, even dummy logins.

Comment: Do you have an fulltext index on the `subject` column?

Comment: The error message seems to be quite clear...

Comment: Show the create index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list (indexes is set)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680472/cant-find-fulltext-index-matching-the-column-list-indexes-is-set)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT index_name(column1);
```

Try this to add a full text index.

Comment: thank you! i used to fix the error: ALTER TABLE `mybb_threads` ADD FULLTEXT (
`subject`
)

Comment: Where are you required to add the following ALTER TABLE .. because i configure table columns from the database