# Error While using MATCH() AGAINST() in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm new in php. I am trying to search mysql dayabase using MATCH AGAINST rather than using LIKE. using this script,

```
    <?php

 if (isset($_GET['q'])){

        error_reporting(-1);



      $query = $_GET['q'];

        $dbh  = new mysqli($host, $user, $password,  $database);

        if ($dbh->connect_error) {
            echo 'Unable to connect to database '. $dbh->connect_error;
        } else {


            if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT index, sura, aya, text FROM bn_bengali WHERE MATCH(sura,text) AGAINST(?) "))

               {
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $query);

                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->bind_result($index, $sura, $aya, $text);


                $stmt->store_result();
              printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);


                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo $sura.'-'.$aya;
                    echo $text;
                    echo '<hr />';
                }
            } else {
                   echo "Prepare failed: (" . $dbh->errno . ") " . $dbh->error;
            }
        }


} // end isset get q
else
{
     echo '<form action="" ><input type="text" name="q"><button>Search</button></form>';
}
    ?>
```

but it's  giving this error,

```
Prepare failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index, sura, aya, text FROM bn_bengali WHERE MATCH(sura,text) AGAINST(?)' at line 1
```

Where is the problem in this Script?

I want to search the database table with match against.

But the same script is working fine with

SELECT sura, aya, text FROM bn_bengali WHERE text LIKE ?

why not match against is working?
Where is the problem in this script?

Comment: Index is Reserved Words in mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` is [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql it must be in backtick

Your query would be

```
SELECT `index`, `sura`, `aya`, `text`...
```

Comment: after changing SELECT `index`, `sura`, `aya`, `text` its giving this error Prepare failed: (1191) Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Comment: Please refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680472/cant-find-fulltext-index-matching-the-column-list-indexes-is-set) for your error

Comment: I already had the text in longtext. but after running this ALTER TABLE bn_bengali ADD FULLTEXT(text); the error is still there

Comment: Use query `ALTER TABLE bn_bengali ADD FULLTEXT(`text`);` and `ALTER TABLE bn_bengali ADD FULLTEXT(`sura`);` in your phpmyadmin and check

Answer (score 1):

`index` is [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql it must be in backtick

Try changing your query to this :

```
SELECT `index`, `sura`, `aya`, `text` FROM...
```

Also I would suggest you to change the column name so that you don't face problem in future as well, as after doing this change there is possibility of getting errors.

Comment: after changing SELECT `index`, `sura`, `aya`, `text` its giving this error Prepare failed: (1191) Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Comment: @HasanBinKarim, please try to change your column name by using `ALTER` query

Comment: I changed the name index to id but the error Prepare failed: (1191) Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list is still there

Comment: have you changed your query also @HasanBinKarim, to `SELECT `id`, `sura`, `aya`, `text` FROM...`

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to add 'backtick' with every column in query. so that if you use even mysql reserve keyword then it will not create any problem. Try below code.

```
  if ($dbh->connect_error) {
            echo 'Unable to connect to database '. $dbh->connect_error;
        } else {


            if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `index`, `sura`, `aya`, `text` FROM bn_bengali WHERE MATCH(sura,text) AGAINST(?) "))

               {
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $query);

                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->bind_result($index, $sura, $aya, $text);


                $stmt->store_result();
              printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);


                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo $sura.'-'.$aya;
                    echo $text;
                    echo '<hr />';
                }
            } else {
                   echo "Prepare failed: (" . $dbh->errno . ") " . $dbh->error;
            }
        }


} // end isset get q
else
{
     echo '<form action="" ><input type="text" name="q"><button>Search</button></form>';
}
    ?>
```