# Multiple word search in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-match-all

I'm facing a issue trying to search with multiple words from my text-box but I cant fix it. The code below is not working, but it works with search `LIKE '%$keywords%'`.

Please see and if you can help me with any solution!

```
 $search = $_POST['search'];
 $search = trim($search);
 $search = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $kerko);
 $keywords = explode(" ", $kerko);

 $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE MATCH(post) AGAINST('$keywords')");


 $sql->execute();
 while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){    
 ?>
```

Comment: What's "not working" ? Do you get any error message ?

Comment: the page is empty, nothing returns, but with LIKE '%$keywords%' returns normally what LIKE can do

Comment: Ok, what's the expected output ? Are each keywords required ?

Comment: Give an example of `$keywords` for which it fails.  Then read about the caveats of what you can put in `AGAINST`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to pass a string to the `MATCH AGAINST` function.

Also, to make sure the post contains every words, like "LIKE" you'll have to add "**+**" sign at the beginning of the required words.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search = trim($search);
$search = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $kerko);
$keywords = explode(" ", $kerko); // create array of keywords

// here we build the string to require all keywords
$keywds_str = "+" . implode(" +", $keywords);
```

And then the SQL query :

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE MATCH(post) AGAINST ('".$keywds_str."')");
```

please note the string concatenation too. In your example, the query had to look for "$keywords" literally.

Last point, enable php error reporting to know what's wrong in your code. A blank page will not help you much.

Hope it helps and good luck.

EDIT :

Since the error message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>
> 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\result.php:82
>
> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\result.php(82): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}
>
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\result.php on line 82

You'll have to index the table column by `FULLTEXT` and enable the `KEYS` on that table too :

```
ALTER TABLE weblinks ENABLE KEYS; 
ALTER TABLE weblinks ADD FULLTEXT(post);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\result.php:82 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\result.php(82): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\result.php on line 82   and line 82 is $sql->execute();

Comment: Ok, when we know the error we can search for a solution. It seems that the searched column was not indexed by `FULLTEXT` (needed to works with `MATCH AGAINST`). See this link on [Can't find FULLTEXT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680472/cant-find-fulltext-index-matching-the-column-list-indexes-is-set) or google it yourself, you'll find a solution.

Comment: Cant fix it, any idea regarding the search please?

Comment: Yes, it says that you can enable the keys on your table : `ALTER TABLE weblinks ENABLE KEYS;`  Or the table is not indexed by FULLTEXT. So you'll have to index it : `ALTER TABLE weblinks ADD FULLTEXT(post);`

Comment: Now it works :) thanks man, probably this will be enough to search with multiple words, cant get deep :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Your welcome. I edit my answer with the content of my last comment. Please share and upvote ! = P

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to convert an array into a string. `explode` returns an array. Try instead

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search = trim($search);
$search = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $kerko);
$keywords = explode(" ", $kerko);

$query = "SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE ";
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $query .= " post LIKE '%$keyword%' OR";
}
$query = rtrim($query, 'OR');

$sql = $conn->prepare($query);    

$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){    
?>
```

Comment: still nothing, also I have updated the $kerko with $search..again nothing

Comment: add a space before `post` in @wogslands example: `$query .= " post LIKE '%$keyword%' OR";` Space is missing so query with multiple keywords will end up like `ORpost LIKE...` in the foreach loop.

Comment: Alternative short version without a foreach loop: `$query = "SELECT * FROM weblinks";` and then: 
  `$query .= empty($keywords) ? '' : " WHERE post LIKE '%". implode("%' OR post LIKE '%", $keywords) ."%'";`